# What data analysis should I use for the following data set?

Tags: mixed-model

I have a data set with individual points.  These points were sampled 5-7 times each year.  The total number of calling birds was recorded.  Years were 2013-2018.  Points were nested in 10 Study Areas. I want to know if there are significant differences in the number of calling birds between SA * Years.

Because the points were sampled multiple times each year, but not all the same number of times, How do I analyze this data?  Points were randomly selected for each Study Area (SA).  Points are unique to that SA only.

Variables in the Data Set:

Points- geographically unique points with a latitude/logitude location.
Randomly selected locations within 10 specified Study Areas.  Each point a unique location.

Study Area:  specified area ranging in size from 10-30 square miles.  Fixed location with boundaries.  10 Separate Study areas.

Date:  Date the point was surveyed.  Such as: 5/1/2013, 4/25/2013, 5/2/2013.....

Year: Year the Point was surveyed.  Such As:  2013, 2014, 2015, 2016, 2017, 2018.

Number of Auditory Pheasant Calls in a 3 minute listening period:  Such as:  0, 1, 2, 3, 4---Dependent Variable-Response.

I want to know if the number of calls varies because of Study Area or Year. Or the interaction of Study Area by Year.

Please help.

Comment: At first sight, a generalized linear mixed model could be useful with a poisson or negative binomial link function (possibly zero-inflated). More here: https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/abs/pii/S0169534709000196 and (free) here: https://peerj.com/articles/4794/

Comment: Please can you edit the question to include a description of all the variables in the dataset.